# Scala - How to define map, where value depends on key?

Tags: scala, dictionary

Is there a way to define a Map, where Map value depends on its key, like

```
Map(key -> f(key), key2 -> f(key2), ...).
```

Comment: I think you define it exactly the same way... `Map(key -> f(key), key2 -> f(key2), ...)`.

Comment: The right question was - is it possible to access Map key from map value.

Comment: uhhhmmmmm..... well..... :O

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Lets say you have your keys in a list like this, and you want to convert it map with squares as values.

```
scala> val keyList = ( 1 to 10 ).toList
keyList: List[Int] = List(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10)

scala> val doSquare = ( x: Int ) => x * x
doSquare: Int => Int = <function1>

// Convert it to the list of tuples - ( key, doSquare( key ) )
scala> val tupleList = keyList.map( key => ( key, doSquare( key ) ) )
tuple: List[(Int, Int)] = List((1,1), (2,4), (3,9), (4,16), (5,25), (6,36), (7,49), (8,64), (9,81), (10,100))

val keyMap = tuple.toMap
keyMap: scala.collection.immutable.Map[Int,Int] = Map(5 -> 25, 10 -> 100, 1 -> 1, 6 -> 36, 9 -> 81, 2 -> 4, 7 -> 49, 3 -> 9, 8 -> 64, 4 -> 16)
```

Or to do it in one line

```
( 1 to 10 ).toList.map( x => ( x, x * x ) ).toMap
```

Or... if you have just few keys... then you can write the specific code

```
Map( 1 -> doSquare( 1 ), 2 -> doSquare( 2 ) )
```

Comment: But that doesn't enforce the relationship. Really, you shouldn't be able to add a key to the map unless the value added is correct for that key. This is not really a map, but a partial function whose domain is the set of keys

Comment: Ummm.... well.... what relationship... ? Here the relationship is defined by the mapping function... So.. I am not sure what are you talking about. And really... what is a map, if not a function mapping keys to values...?

Comment: The OP wants to define a Map where the values relate to the key - value = f(key). I think it should be impossible to add a key/value for which that relationship does not hold. That means in practice, the value never needs to be specified. And yes, a Map is a partial function from keys to values, but this one has defined that the value = f(key)

Comment: Umm... and where did you see that a key-value pair which breaks the relationship... ? `( 1 to 10 ).toList.map( x => ( x, x * x ) ).toMap`... the relationthip is `value = key * key`

Comment: I can (accidentally) write  (x=> (x , x+x) and get something different without an error. I think it would be nice to be able to declare a DependentMap(f) and have that enforced.  Not really important, I just think an answer that says "if you want the value to be f(key) then add   key -> f(key)" isn't really adding much. The OP already did that.

Comment: Well... true... Something like a `DependantMap` would have been nice... but I think that applies only if we want a `mutable map`. Also you can (accidentally) write `f = ( x => ( x, x+ x ) )` and then `DependentMap( f )`. In both the cases the function is being provided just once... so any accidental mistake will be deadly.... no matter what we use.

Comment: No, becasue you might then go on to do `map updated <some key/value pair that doesn't comply>`. Anyway, I think you got my point.

Answer (score 10):

You're looking at this the wrong way...

A `Map[K,V]` is also an instance of `Partialfunction[K,V]`.  So change everywhere you're using your `Map` type (vals, method params, etc.) to be a `PartialFunction`.

Then you can just work with `f` directly, or supply a `Map[K,V]` as the instance wherever you don't have a simple algebraic relationship between keys and values.

e.g.

```
def methodUsingMapping(x: PartialFunction[Int,Boolean]) = ...

//then
val myMap = Map(1->true, 2->true, 3->false)
methodUsingMapping(myMap)


//or
val isEven = PartialFunction(n: Int => n % 2 == 0)
methodUsingMapping(isEven)

//or
//note: case statements in a block is the smart way
//      to define a partial function
//      In this version, the result isn't even defined for odd numbers
val isEven: PartialFunction[Int,Boolean] = {
  case n: Int if n % 2 == 0 => true
}
methodUsingMapping(isEven)
```

You also might also want to consider using `(K) => Option[V]`, in which case you can supply an instance of the type via the `lift` method, which maps inherit from `PartialFunction`

e.g.

```
def methodUsingMapping(x: (Int)=>Option[Boolean]) = ...

//then
val myMap = Map(1->true, 2->true, 3->false)
methodUsingMapping(myMap.lift)

//or
def isEven(n: Int) = Some(n % 2 == 0)
methodUsingMapping(isEven)

//or
def isEven(n: Int) = n % 2 == 0
methodUsingMapping(x => Some(isEven(x)))
```

Answer (score 4):

Because you only need to define 4 methods to make a `Map` trait implementation, you could just roll your own:

```
trait MapWithRelationship[K, +V] extends Map[K, V] {
  self =>
  def pred: (K, Any) => Boolean
  def underlying: Map[K, V]
  def get(key: K): Option[V] = underlying.get(key)
  def iterator: Iterator[(K, V)] = underlying.iterator
  def + [V1 >: V](kv: (K, V1)): MapWithRelationship[K, V1] = {
    val (k, v) = kv
    if (pred(k, v)) {
      new MapWithRelationship[K, V1] {
        val pred = self.pred
        val underlying = self.underlying + kv
      }
    } else {
      throw new Exception(s"Key-value pair $kv failed MapWithRelationship predicate")
    }
  }
  def -(key: K): MapWithRelationship[K, V] =
    new MapWithRelationship[K, V] {
      val pred = self.pred
      val underlying = self.underlying - key
    }
}

object MapWithRelationship {
  def apply[K, V](rule: (K, Any) => Boolean)(pairs: (K, V)*) = {
    val empty = new MapWithRelationship[K, V] { 
      def pred = rule 
      def underlying = Map.empty[K, V]
    }
    pairs.foldLeft(empty)(_ + _)
  }
}
```

Then you can use as such:

```
scala> val x = MapWithRelationship[Int, Int]((k, v) => v == k * k)()
x: MapWithRelationship[Int,Int] = Map()

scala> val x2 = x + (1 -> 1)
x2: MapWithRelationship[Int,Int] = Map(1 -> 1)

scala> val x3 = x + (5 -> 25)
x3: MapWithRelationship[Int,Int] = Map(5 -> 25)

scala> val x4 = x + (6 -> "foo")
java.lang.Exception: Key-value pair (6,foo) failed MapWithRelationship predicate
  at MapWithRelationship$class.$plus(<console>:21)
  at MapWithRelationship$$anon$3.$plus(<console>:33)
  ... 32 elided
```

Comment: I just realized that making the value of `rule` be of type `Any` really restricts the kind of comparisons that can be done. It's a bit awkward to try to give it an appropriate type because of the way `+` is allowed to widen the value type of the map.

Answer (score 1):

You could make an infinite map of squares using:

```
val mySquareMap = Map.empty[Int, Int].withDefault(d => d * d)
```

This map will still have `+`, `get`, `iterator` and other methods that won't work as desired, but if you need a read-only map that returns squares, this would work.

Of course, it would be more efficient and probably clearer to just use:

```
val mySquare = (d:Int) => d * d
```

as a function.  However, the above `Map` might be useful if you need to use some API that requires that type.

To have a more full-fledged solution for this, you might be better off building your own class that extends `Map[Int, Int]` that overrides `get` to return the square of its argument.

Comment: That's pretty much  the same as using mySquareMap = { d => d*d}. Only less efficient :)

Comment: Sure -- I was thinking he might be using an API that requires a `Map`

Comment: In that case, you can *still* use the function, then only wrap it in `Map.empty[Int, Int].withDefault(theFunc)` at the point of use.